# Erectile dysfunction has led to an unsatisfying marriage with my husband; would it be a sin to ask for divorce?

Tags: nikah, talaq

I have been married for four years and Allah has blessed us with a son. Ever since my son was born my husband has had issues being intimate with me. When I asked, he gave me different reasons (which were lies).  After some time, I came to find out that he has erectile issues.

I sought different ways to help him and even went for duas and local forms of medicine. The problem remained I therefore tried another maalim who conducted different duas for us. But my husband does not show cooperation and does not make any effort in trying to find a cure for what he is going through. We might try to have sex at night and fail, but in the morning he will act as if nothing is wrong. He told me he had gone to the hospital once, but every time I try to ask him on the situation he just brushes the topic off or comes up with another story that isn't true.

I am no longer in love with this man because now every little thing he does irritates me. If I ask for talaq will I be committing a sin?

Answer (score 2):

First, as far as your husband's condition is not chronic, you should support him and ask for treatment.

Then, you have two options: either to continue with the marriage or to ask for divorce after the husband has been given one year respite to seek treatment. An-Nafraawi, an Islamic scholar stated that a husband should be given one-year respite if his wife finds him unable to have intercourse with her. This would also apply to the case where the wife did not know about her husband’s impotence at the time of their marriage.